# html code appears in my text view in RSS feed app

Tags: iphone, rss, uitextview

i got an rss feed app. All is working ok apart from the fact that in my "description" textView
(detail of the rss) the text appears in html!

any ideas in what is going on?

thanks!

Comment: In iPhone OS 2.x There was an undocumented method that shows the content in HTML -[UITextView setContentToHTMLString:(NSString*)str]; If you are not using this, and don't show some code there is no way we can say something for sure ;)

Comment: no i m not using this. are there any other sources i can find to actually make this happen? and the question is: SHOULD i be using this code????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have found the solution using a wbview with loadHTMLString.

however i would like to ask what is the difference between these two rss feeds:

http://newsrss.bbc.co.uk/rss/sportonline_world_edition/front_page/rss.xml

and this for example:

http://feeds.feedburner.com/pitsirikos/uPfN

in the first one i can get the textview to display the contents as they should appear while in the second one i get html code in the textview!

my code remains the same in both cases...

Answer (score 0):

The key difference between them is that the latter contains prefix tags 
e.g.  and 
Do you use NSXMLParser or libxml2 ? are you doing a strcmp with the element name ?